# What should a find function return in failure result?

Tags: c++, function, return

The question has been bothering me since I first realized the List class, where I needed a method to find nodes which data is equal to input value. If ==, then, obviously, return immediately. But otherwise? What should it do then?

I thought about throwing an exception, but how the program will behave when from the function call it will recognizes the failure?

```
Node* find_node(const T &data) {
    if (is_empty())
        std::exit(1);

    Node *temp = _head;

    while (temp != nullptr) {
        if (temp->_data == data)
            break;
        temp = temp->_next;
    }     

    return temp;
}
```

Well, I kind kind of expect it to return a pointer to a node if search succeeded, so I could access its value in function's call if needed.

Comment: For a function that returns a pointer, when it fails it's common to return a *null* pointer. Which of course needs to be checked for.

Comment: It is already returning `nullptr`. Seems ok.

Comment: It might be interesting to use this pattern: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_type

Comment: Calling exit() if the list is empty is not a good idea.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Sorry, I haven't touched this project in weeks. Will it be okay to return nullptr then?

Comment: So if the list is empty, pull the rug out from under the client and terminate the program?  Seriously?

Comment: In any case the empty list should behave the same way as the not-found case for non-empty lists, because whatever is searched for cannot be found in an empty list.

Comment: Yes, returning nullptr, as you do if  the item is not found, is the best idea. You should almost never call exit.

Answer (score 1):

`nullptr` is the correct return value for when the search fails. This is the advantage of using a pointer rather than a reference, as you could return a reference if you knew that you were always going to have a value.

The calling code should always check for `nullptr` when receiving a pointer from the function call, and handle the fact that the search failed.

The [C++ Core Guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#f60-prefer-t-over-t-when-no-argument-is-a-valid-option) state, in F.60:

> **Prefer T* over T& when "no argument" is a valid option**
>
> A pointer (T*) can be a nullptr and a reference (T&) cannot, there is no valid "null reference". Sometimes having nullptr as an alternative to indicated "no object" is useful, but if it is not, a reference is notationally simpler and might yield better code.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of common ways of handling this situation. The correct one largely depends on what type of thing you're returning.

1. If you're returning an iterator, you normally want to return the "one past the end" iterator that the caller passed to define the range you were searching.
2. With pointers you typically return a null pointer (which is what the code in the question actually does, though perhaps you didn't realize that, or have forgotten).
3. If you're returning a reference, you have a couple of choices. One it to change the return type from `foo &` to an `optional<foo &>`. Another is to define a single "null" object, and return a reference to that upon failure.